# NoMachine: Error is 54, connection reset by peer. Has to update & restart nx server everytime

Tags: macos, connection, nomachine

I am a new user of NoMachine. I am trying to connect from my Mac to a Virtual Box on Ubuntu.

I installed NoMachine for Linux RPM x86_64 `https://www.nomachine.com/download/download&id=12` on my virtual box, and a Mac version NoMachine on my Mac as client.

I `rpm` the package on VB, and connected from Mac by NX port 4000. It was fine and connection was successful, I played with them for a while. After around half an hour, I cannot connect to the VB any more with the error of `Error is 54, connection reset by peer`.

I tried these twice. All worked initially, then came across the error 54. I configed by the ifconfig, inet addr of the vb.

Extra info. The connection to Ubuntu has been working all the time.

Just found this:

```
sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --restart                          ~
NX> 162 Disabled service: nxserver.
NX> 162 Disabled service: nxnode.
NX> 162 Disabled service: nxd.
NX> 161 Enabled service: nxserver.
NX> 162 Disabled service: nxd.

sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --status                           ~
NX> 161 Enabled service: nxserver.
NX> 162 Disabled service: nxnode.
NX> 162 Disabled service: nxd.
```

https://www.nomachine.com/TR02L04291   This helped. Run update and it worked.

However, after a certain time, it stop working and that error came again. Has to log into virtual box, update and restart the nx server, then the connection can be established again. What's wrong....?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is:

```
sudo chown  nx:root /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg
sudo chown  nx:root /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg
sudo chown  -R nx:nx /usr/NX/var/tmp/nx
sudo chown  nx:nx /usr/NX/var/run/nxserver.pid
sudo chown  nx:nx /usr/NX/var/db/ports.lock

sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --startup
```

Taken from the NoMachine website: https://www.nomachine.com/TR01N06344